# 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'images'

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I want to retrieve a list of information belonging to a certain field in a database. But , I am getting 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'images'error.

models.py

```
class Business(models.Model):
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    business_location = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    business_description = models.TextField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.business_name

 class BusinessImage(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, related_name='images', on_delete =models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

views.py

```
def get_data1(request, *args, **kwargs):
    b= Business.objects.filter(business_name="some-name")
    image_list = b.images.all()
    c = {'image_list': image_list}
    return render(request, "index.html", c)
```

This error got solved using this code but not seeing anything in template:
views.py

```
def get_data1(request, *args, **kwargs):
b= BusinessImage.objects.filter(business__business_name="some-name")
image_list = b.values_list('image',flat = True)
c = {'image_list': image_list}
return render(request, "index.html", c)
```

index.html

```
{% for i in image_list %}
  <img src ="{{ i.image.url}}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your index.html

Answer (score 0):

For your case you need to use `values_list`:

```
b= Business.objects.filter(business_name="some-name")
image_list = b.values_list(
    'images',
     flat=True
).distinct(
    'images',
)
```

in your template,

```
{% for i in image_list %}
    <img src ="{{ i.images.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Or you can fetch your images directly:

```
b= Business.objects.filter(business_name="some-name")
image_list = b.values_list(
    'images__image',
     flat=True
).distinct(
    'images__image',
)
```

in your template,

```
{% for i in image_list %}
    <img src ="{{ i.url }}"> 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: sorry, this didn't work I tried without the distinct word because it is not supported by MY-SQL and sqlite both. Again, it is not being able to display images.

Answer (score 0):

filter will return you query set you have to use for loop for this. And It is image not images please fix this like this.

```
def get_data1(request, *args, **kwargs):
b= BusinessImage.objects.filter(business__business_name="some-name")
image_list = b.values_list('image',flat = True)
c = {'image_list': image_list}
return render(request, "index.html", c)
```

after updating the question-

```
b= BusinessImage.objects.filter(business__business_name="some-name")
return render(request, "index.html", b)
```

in index.html

```
{% for bb in b %}
        <img src="{{ bb.image.url }}">
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: the error got solved but I am not seeing anything in template. {% for i in image_list %}
    {{ i.image.url}}
{% endfor %}

Comment: then you have to send the full instance to "index.html"

Comment: I'm getting the error TypeError at context must be a dict rather than QuerySet.

Comment: ok just try now this might help otherwise you have to help yourself.